# PassportJS - multiple local strategies not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm developing a nodejs application and a I need two local strategies. The registration of both goes well, the problem is when I try to login with the enterprise user.

Heres is my code:

```
let User = require('./models/userModel')
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

let Enterprise = require('./models/enterpriseModel')
let EnterpriseStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use('enterprise-local', new EnterpriseStrategy(Enterprise.authenticate()))
passport.serializeUser(Enterprise.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Enterprise.deserializeUser());


// Refactored code. But returns an error. ReferenceERROR: isUser is not defined
// passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
//   if (isUser(user)) {
//     done(null, User.serializeUser())
//   } else if (isEnterprise(user)) {
//     done(null, Enterprise.serializeUser())
//   }
// });
```

Some people told me that the problem is that I'm overriding the serialization. Then I used this commented code. But also return an error. isUser is not defined.

Comment: where are you defining isUser function?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not defining. This commented code was a solution propused by a random guy on internet. In fact, seems that the problem is that was overriding the serialization of the users. I don't know how to define this function.

Comment: are you using two different login strategies for user and enterprises or are you making the seperation on the database storage?

Comment: Two different strategies. I'have separated schemas for each kind of user(enterprise and normal user)